# Pepper plant identification

Tags: identification, peppers

[image][image]

Need help identifying this pepper. Any help would be appreciated. Got this plant from family when it was a seedling but was given no information.

Comment: This looks like a banana pepper.  A pepperoncini. A very mild Italian pepper.  Yummm.  Can't be sure.  someone will come along with a more substantial ID.

Comment: The shape is like a Pepperoncini. Banana peppers are almost always pointed.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be possible to get a 100% correct ID just from looking at the plant. You say you were given the plant by family as a seedling; if the seedling grew from seed they had saved themselves, chili pepper varieties do not come true from seed unless they are grown in isolation, with other plants of the same variety. If it was bought seed, then whoever planted it and grew it on should know which variety it is; there are hundreds of varieties of pepper. As the fruits develop, it might be possible to take a better guess, but otherwise, it's a case of trying the fruits to see what they're like.